# Jquery Listeners Not Working after performing load()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a DIV that contains paginated results of a MySQL query.

I was attempting to use the .load() function to change the content of the DIV based upon the page number clicked.

The functionality worked perfect except for the other event listeners stopped working properly.  In the query results I had several listeners for clicking on different buttons etc which stopped working once I navigated away from page 1 even though the parent page never changes and the ids and names of the content is the same.

This is the jquery I was using.

```
$('input[name="pagenumbutton"]').click(function(){
  var thispagenum = this.value;
  var thispagestart = (thispagenum - 1) * 10;
  $("#result").load("querydb.php", "thispagestart="+thispagestart);  
});
```

after clicking any of the inputs named pagenumbutton the result div content would update but then the following jquery would no longer fire.

```
$('img[name="appdetailimg"]').click(function(){
  var appName = $(this).parent().parent().children().get(0).textContent;
  var appDetail = $(this).parent().children().get(1).value;

  document.getElementById('detaildivtd').textContent = appName + " : DETAIL";
  document.getElementById('detailtext').value = appDetail;

  $("div#fuzz").fadeIn();
  $("div#detaildiv").center();
  $("div#detaildiv").show();
});
```

Everything works perfectly fine if I change the page statically and reload the entire index page but not when I use the .load() function to only reload the div.

Is this expected behavior with the .load() function or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the amazing and quick responses.

I used .on() for each of the elements that were reloaded and it all works great now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers apply to the ***specific*** element they are applied to.  If the element is replaced, even by an identical element, the handler will no longer exist.

jQuery solves this with `live`, `delegate`, and `on`, the former two being deprecated for the latter.

If you apply the handler using `on`, you attach it to a parent element that does not change, so it can be triggered as the child elements are modified:

```
$('#result').on('click','img[name="appdetailimg"]', function(){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. The 'click' event is bound to currently accessible elements in this call. So, anything you add to the page after the 'click' event is bound, won't be bound.

You need to take a look at '[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)', '[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)', and '[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)'.

```
// change to "live" and bind the "click" event
// "click" event will bind to all selected elements in the future
$('img[name="appdetailimg"]').live('click', function(){
  var appName = $(this).parent().parent().children().get(0).textContent;
  var appDetail = $(this).parent().children().get(1).value;

  document.getElementById('detaildivtd').textContent = appName + " : DETAIL";
  document.getElementById('detailtext').value = appDetail;

  $("div#fuzz").fadeIn();
  $("div#detaildiv").center();
  $("div#detaildiv").show();
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that `live` and `delegate` are deprecated in favor of `on` for version 1.7+

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use `.live()` it's deprecated and watches the whole DOM... that's certainly excess

It's not got anything to do with load, it has to do with your event binding match with what you're doing with load();

The click function is bound to elements that are available in the DOM when that piece of JavaScript is called.

Try this instead:

```
$('.wrapper').delegate('input[name="pagenumbutton"]', 'click', function(){
      var thispagenum = this.value;
      var thispagestart = (thispagenum - 1) * 10;
      $("#result").load("querydb.php", "thispagestart="+thispagestart);  
    });
    $('.wrapper').delegate('img[name="appdetailimg"]', "click", function(){
      var appName = $(this).parent().parent().children().get(0).textContent;
      var appDetail = $(this).parent().children().get(1).value;

      document.getElementById('detaildivtd').textContent = appName + " : DETAIL";
      document.getElementById('detailtext').value = appDetail;

      $("div#fuzz").fadeIn();
      $("div#detaildiv").center();
      $("div#detaildiv").show();
    });
```

Comment: `delegate` is deprecated as well since 1.7... =)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the second code-block references elements in the area that reloads.  In that case, use 'delegate' (replace 'body' with a static container for your elements):

```
$('body').on('img[name="appdetailimg"]', 'click', function(){
  var appName = $(this).parent().parent().children().get(0).textContent;
  var appDetail = $(this).parent().children().get(1).value;

  document.getElementById('detaildivtd').textContent = appName + " : DETAIL";
  document.getElementById('detailtext').value = appDetail;

  $("div#fuzz").fadeIn();
  $("div#detaildiv").center();
  $("div#detaildiv").show();
});
```

Comment: `delegate` is deprecated since jquery 1.7

Answer (score 0):

`click` only attack functions to elemetes that were rendered when the `click` attach performed.

you should use JQuery `on`\ `live`\ `delegate` function, based on your JQuery version:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` version:

```
$('body').on('click', 'img[name="appdetailimg]', function(){
      var appName = $(this).parent().parent().children().get(0).textContent;
      var appDetail = $(this).parent().children().get(1).value;

      document.getElementById('detaildivtd').textContent = appName + " : DETAIL";
      document.getElementById('detailtext').value = appDetail;

      $("div#fuzz").fadeIn();
      $("div#detaildiv").center();
      $("div#detaildiv").show();   
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

@swatkins is right use:

```
$('body').delegate('img[name="appdetailimg"]', 'click', function(){.....}
```

Comment: @gdoron actually not when i was trying to format it did not come out how i wanted it since I originally copied what the asker had, if you want me to expand on why delegate() is a viable way of solving this particular issue feel free to post a question and in a very civil manner I'll oblige you with a more complete answer.